# Why promise.resolve wait forever in this case?

Tags: node.js, promise

I am a nodejs's newbie. I'm testing a promise and have an issue.
Here's my issue.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', async function(req,res){
    console.log(222);
    res.send("Hello!!!");
    let check;
    try {
        console.log(3333);
        check = await test();
        console.log(4444);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("Error : ", err);
    }
    console.log(111, check);
});

function test () {
    return new Promise (resolve => {
        console.log(5555);
        app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
            count = count + 1;
            res.send(count.toString());
            resolve("hahahaha");
        })
    })
}

app.listen(9000, function(){
    console.log("hehehehe");
});
```

In a get 'http://localhost:9000' callback, I wait for 'http://localhost:9000/test' result to do something. The thing is, it's working fine for the first time. But since the 2nd, the promise.resolve() function doesn't work.
Here is my first time log:

```
hehehehe
222
3333
5555
4444
111 'hahahaha'
```

And here is my second time log :

```
222
3333
5555
```

the `promise.resovle()` doesn't work. It's waiting forever and I don't understand.

EDIT : Here is the solution for using EventEmitter to do signup and smsVerifyCode after modified by the help of Mr. @Aritra Chakraborty

```
var express = require('express');
var userControler = require('../Controler/user');
var router = express.Router();
var utils = require('../Helper/Utils');
var user_model = require('../Models/user');
const TIMEOUT_VERIFY = 300000;
const CODE_EXPIRED = 0;
const CODE_VALID = 1;
const CODE_INVALID = 2;
const CONTACT_EXISTED = 3;
const DATABASE_ABUSED = 4;
const events = require('events');
const emitter  = new events.EventEmitter();

function timeout_verify_sms_emitter (time) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        emitter.emit('timeout_sms');
    }, time);
}

function verify_code(codeGen) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        emitter.on("verifySMS", (data)=>{

            if (data === codeGen) {
                resolve(CODE_VALID);
            }
            else {
                resolve(CODE_INVALID);
            }
        })
        emitter.on('timeout_sms', () =>{
            resolve(CODE_EXPIRED);
        });
    })
}

router.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.send("Welcome to the Earth!!!");
})

router.post('/signup', async function(req,res){
    let verifyCode;
    let checkContact;
    let codeGen = utils.generateCode();
    try {
        checkContact = await user_model.checkContact(userData.contact);
        if (checkContact === true) {
            res.send(CONTACT_EXISTED);
        }
        else {
            //call send sms to contact function here
            //exam : sendSMS(contact)
            //
            timeout_verify_sms_emitter(TIMEOUT_VERIFY);
            verifyCode = await verify_code(codeGen);
        }
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log("Error : ", err);
    }

    if (verifyCode === CODE_EXPIRED) {
        res.send(CODE_EXPIRED);
    }
    else if (verifyCode === CODE_VALID) {
        var result = userControler.processUserData(req.body);
        if (result) {
            res.send(CODE_VALID);
        }
        else {
            res.send(DATABASE_ABUSED);
        }
    }
    else {
        res.send (CODE_INVALID);
    }
})

router.post('/signup/verifySMS', function(req, res){
    emitter.emit("verifySMS", req.body.smsCode);
})

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: It will only work once you go back to "/" and then to "/test"

Comment: Can you explain for me?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? in this code "whenever you do a get request to `/` you are CREATING a `/test` path." So only running the `/test` path after running the `/` path the promise will resolve. But whatever you are trying to do I think you should change the code.

Comment: @AritraChakraborty yeah i know that. But when i run /test after / in the second time, the promise.resolve() doesn't work. And that is my issue

Comment: @AritraChakraborty i'm trying to do with my signup module. User send a post request '/signup'. At server, in router.post('/signup'). I wait for sms code which is sent by user with '/signup/sms' post request to verify

Comment: @AritraChakraborty and above is my test code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the above code:
Whenever you do a get request to `/` you are CREATING a `/test` path.

So, the first time it works because `/test` path has one handler.
Second or more time it doesn't works because,

1. The `/test` route has multiple handler now.
2. How express works is, routes get executed according to their declaration time. (Think middlewares)
3. Now, Second time the `/test` will have 2 handlers. And when you hit `/test` the first handler runs. And as this is not a middlware it doesn't go to the next handler. Now, the first handler has a different `resolve` function then the second one. So the second `resolve` function doesn't run at all.(Think closure)

For what are you trying to do most web implementations use long polling. Because if you wait too long for the second route it will throw a timeout error. Means you periodically hit an api to get the status of something. Means you create 3 routes.

1. A main route, like `/signup`
2. A second route like `/sendsms`
3. A third route where you send a particual identifier and it returns some positve/negative value. like `/sendsms/check`, where you might pass the phone number.

Otherwise if you don't care about timeouts you can use `EventEmitter` inside the `/test` route.

**EDIT1:**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
const events = require('events');
const emitter  = new events.EventEmitter();
let count = 0;
app.get('/', async function (req, res) {
    console.log(222);
    res.send("Hello!!!");
    let check;
    try {
        console.log(3333);
        check = await test();
        console.log(4444);
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log("Error : ", err);
    }
    console.log(111, check);
});
app.get('/test', function (req, res) {
    count = count + 1;
    emitter.emit("test",count.toString());
    res.send(count.toString());

})
function test(){
    return new Promise((res)=>{
        emitter.on("test", (data)=>{
            res(data);
        })
    })
}
app.listen(9000, function () {
    console.log("hehehehe");
});
```

**EDIT2:**
Regarding the solution, you need to handle the timeout differently. Let's say your timeout is 3sec. And the SMS route took 100sec to get a response or maybe it didn't even got a response. Then your function will be stuck there.

```
function test(sendSMSTime) {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        emitter.on("test", (data) => {
            .
            .
            res(data);
        })
        emitter.on('timeout', rej);//On timeout it will run.
    })
}
function timeoutEmitter(timeout) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        emitter.emit('timeout');
    }, timeout)
}
app.post('/signup', async function (req, res) {
    try {
        timeoutEmitter(3000);
        .
        .
    }catch{

    }
});
```

Comment: thank you very much!!! Now i understand why my test code is not working

Comment: Edited the code to use event emitters. Feel free to accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: Yeah, i have a solution for the timeout of sms verification. I still using EventEmitter. Can you check my solution?

Comment: Add it as EDIT of your question. it doesn't answer the question, the question is `Why promise.resolve wait forever in this case?`. Not code.

Comment: Yeah, i've editted my question. Can you check my solution? Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Edited the answer.

Comment: oh sorry, i've just checked your solution because i had some business yesterday. And your solution is very good. But instead of using emitter.on('timeout', rej), i resolve as a CODE_EXPIRED. I will update in EDIT of the question

Comment: i've editted my question and use your solution. Can you check it mr @Aritra Chakraborty

Comment: i think you should make another question to discuss the solution.

Comment: yeah, i will do it. Anyway, thanks for your help so much

Comment: if it helped you and answered your question please accept the answer so that others can find it useful as well. there wil be one gray tick button.